# How to change the direction of a font awesome icon?

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I am using the font-awsome library to show a unlock icon .

So, By default the direction is in right direction, I want to change that to the left.

```
<i class="fas fa-unlock-alt"></i>
```

SO, is there any way through which I can change the direction of the unlock icon ?

Comment: `fa-flip-horizontal`

Comment: BTW you can use css(in case you won't use  `font-awesome` and you want to change direction)            with `transform: scaleX(-1)` :https://jsfiddle.net/29ctojxb/

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `fa-flip-horizontal` class as documented [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/rotating-icons).

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fas fa-unlock-alt"></i>
<i class="fas fa-unlock-alt fa-flip-horizontal"></i>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can rotate and flip icons with font awesome. In your case you can try this:

```
<i class="fas fa-unlock-alt fa-flip-horizontal"></i>
```

Check out this link for more information https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/rotating-icons

Answer (score 1):

Considering the JS+SVG version you can use `flip-h` to flip the icon horizontally

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js"></script>

<i class="fas fa-unlock-alt" data-fa-transform="flip-h"></i>
```

More details: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/power-transforms